# Get parent directory of current directory in Ruby

Tags: ruby, directory

I understand I can get current directory by

```
$CurrentDir = Dir.pwd
```

How about parent directory of current directory?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
File.expand_path("..", Dir.pwd)
```

Comment: @Niklas: Or `File.expand_path('..')`, the [default `dir_string`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path) is `'.'`.

Comment: The solution suggested above did not work for me using `ruby 2.1.5`. The following did ... `File.dirname(File.expand_path('..', __FILE__))`

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps the simplest solution:

```
puts File.expand_path('../.')
```

Comment: Why not just `File.expand_path('..')`?

Comment: @muistooshort indeed interesting, and definitly useful to know, thanks ;)

Comment: Your answer piqued my curiosity to check the spec for `File.expand_path` so thanks for that.

Answer (score 16):

I think an even simpler solution is to use `File.dirname`:

```
2.3.0 :005 > Dir.pwd
 => "/Users/kbennett/temp"
2.3.0 :006 > File.dirname(Dir.pwd)
 => "/Users/kbennett"
2.3.0 :007 > File.basename(Dir.pwd)
 => "temp"
```

`File.basename` returns the component of the path that `File.dirname` does not.

This, of course, works only if the filespec is absolute and not relative.  To be sure to make it absolute one could do this:

```
2.3.0 :008 > File.expand_path('.')
 => "/Users/kbennett/temp"
2.3.0 :009 > File.dirname(File.expand_path('.'))
 => "/Users/kbennett"
```

Comment: My answer here works, but is not as expressive and clear as the other answers.

Answer (score 6):

In modern Ruby you should definitely use [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-c-getwd).

```
Pathname.getwd.parent
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. You'd probably almost always need to call `.to_s` on that to convert it to a String (it's a Pathname).

Comment: In my experience you rarely need `to_s`, but rather you should embrace Pathname everywhere for file names, rather than String.