# How to get the name of the folders from the file name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Apologies, as I am not into Ruby coding, and I am writing a code to get the folder names of the structures from the file path.

For example, if I have a file in **E:/aaa/bbb/ccc/filename.jpg**

How can I get the folder names **aaa**, **bbb**, and **ccc**? I know only the parent folder **ccc** to use *File.nakeddir*, but for aaa and bbb, how to get them?

Thank you!

Comment: May be you can check this link [Get parent directory of current directory in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660732/get-parent-directory-of-current-directory-in-ruby)

Comment: Did you try searching for it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206714/can-a-ruby-script-tell-what-directory-it-s-in

Comment: There is no rush to select an answer but if at least one answer is useful please select the one you prefer. I realize that at this time there is only one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Pathname` class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) from the Ruby standard library can be used to break down paths into their constituent parts:

```
require 'pathname'
path = Pathname.new("E:/aaa/bbb/ccc/filename.jpg")
path.dirname.each_filename.drop(1) # ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

Comment: `drop(1)` removes the `aaa` as well. `drop(1)` is not necessary here.

Comment: @Rajagopalan incorrect - it removes `E:`.

Comment: Nope! That's wrong. Which Ruby Version are you using? `path.dirname.each_filename.to_a` returns `["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]`

Comment: This was just tested on ruby 2.7.0p0

Comment: I think they have changed from `2.7.1`. Because I have tested in `2.7.1` and `3.0`.

Comment: @Rajagopalan - makes sense. Should probally get around to updating the VM I use for stackoverflow examples some day.

Comment: Hey wait! Nope. I checked in ruby2.6.5 as well, it works the same way as it does in ruby 3.0. Don't know what's happening in your end. If I executes with drop(1) then my output is `["bbb", "ccc"]`

Comment: Could it be a windows thing since it as after all a windows path? I'm running it on a linux VM.

Comment: Ah! Yes. that might be the case I think!